# Can Kun'yomi and On'yomi be mixed? Can a distant On'yomi reading be used?

Tags: kanji, readings, adjectives, names

The title is pretty catchy on its own, but I'm already familiar with creating good Japanese names. I know about kanji and their meanings, but I'm at a loss. I have a few doubts. The first one: Can Kun'yomi and On'yomi be mixed? And when it comes to On'yomi, can a specific reading be "chosen" (assuming the kanji name has multiple readings and one of them is a very distant one like "Tai"), can I still use "Tai" anyway? The second question is about naming something that already exists, for example, the word "Tsumetai". I would love to know if this could become a name. Well, these are my doubts (I apologize for any spelling mistakes or poor explanations, as my English is terrible and my writing is not great).

Comment: Coming up with a new unique Japanese name is difficult even for native Japanese speakers who have lived for decades. There are many names that are common today but would have been impossible 50 or 300 years ago, and vice versa. If you're already fluent in ordinary Japanese sentences and really want to do this, start by looking at 100 actual Japanese names from the era you're interested in.

Answer (score 1):

> Can Kun'yomi and On'yomi mix?

Yes, there are such words.

For 2-kanji words, there are terms [重{じゅう}箱{ばこ}読{よ}み](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%87%8D%E7%AE%B1%E8%AA%AD%E3%81%BF) (on'yomi + kun'yomi) and [湯{ゆ}桶{とう}読み{よみ}](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%B9%AF%E6%A1%B6%E8%AA%AD%E3%81%BF) (kun'yomi + on'yomi).

[Wiktionary: Category:Japanese_terms_read_with_jūbakoyomi](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Japanese_terms_read_with_j%C5%ABbakoyomi)

[Wiktionary: Category:Japanese_terms_read_with_yutōyomi](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Japanese_terms_read_with_yut%C5%8Dyomi)

> On'yomi can be "chosen" (assuming the kanji has multiple readings and a very distant one is "Tai" could I use Tai anyway?)

For newly invented names, yes.

Kanji also have [nanori (名{な}乗{の}り)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanori) readings, which are used only in proper names.

> the second is about naming something that already exists, for example the word Tsumetai. I would love to know if this could become a name

I think that names derived from adjectives more likely use Middle/Classical Japanese form of Terminal/Conclusive, which had suffix 〜し. E.g. modern 広{ひろ}い had Middle/Classical Japanese Terminal/Conclusive 広{ひろ}し. Kanji used for spelling names are often different from kanji used for common noun, from which these names originate.

Some examples:

[よし](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%82%88%E3%81%97) (modern adjective 良{よ}い/善{よ}い/... and 良{い}い/善{い}い/...)

[あつし](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%82%E3%81%A4%E3%81%97) (modern adjective 厚{あつ}い/篤{あつ}い)

[きよし](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%8D%E3%82%88%E3%81%97) (modern adjective 清{きよ}い)

[ひろし](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%B2%E3%82%8D%E3%81%97) (modern adjective 広{ひろ}い)

So in your example, I would suggest つめたし for name instead of つめたい.

Some names are derived from verbs, either Terminal/Conclusive or Continuative, also often from Middle/Classical Japanese form (which differed from modern form only for some verbs). Examples:

[さとる](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%95%E3%81%A8%E3%82%8B) (verb 悟{さと}る "to perceive, to understand, to come to enlightenment")

[ひろむ](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%B2%E3%82%8D%E3%82%80) (modern verb 広{ひろ}める/弘{ひろ}める/拡{ひろ}める "to broaden, to widen" ← Middle Japanese verb 広{ひろ}む/弘{ひろ}む/拡{ひろ}む)

[めぐみ](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%82%81%E3%81%90%E3%81%BF) (verb 恵{めぐ}む "to bless")

[こおり](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%93%E3%81%8A%E3%82%8A) (verb 凍{こお}る "to freeze")

Comment: Friend, I would like to know... That idea you mentioned above in the verb "to freeze", would the reading be "Koru" or "Kooru" as a proper name?  and one more thing, could this kanji "独" become a name? (I intend to use it with the "Hitori" reading.)

Comment: @SATORU菩薩 [JMnedict / ENAMDICT dictionary](https://www.edrdg.org/enamdict/enamdict_doc.html) apparently already includes 凍(こおる/Kooru) and also several kanji spellings for こおり/Koori: 古織, 呼音鈴, 湖織, 小緒吏, 小織, 氷, but all (こおる/Kooru and こおり/Koori) are marked as **female** names.

Comment: JMnedict / ENAMDICT dictionary includes 独(どく/Doku) and 独(ひとり/Hitori), both currently marked as given names with gender not specified.

Comment: Thank you very much!